# SQL create a list of dates based on current date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have a column of dates that range from 2015-06 to 2013-04. The date range will grow as I put in more data. How do I write a query where the date is always a X amount of months before the current date?

```
date
2015-06
2015-05
2015-04
2015-03
2015-02
```

for example I want it to be:

```
Select *
From dbo.name
Where date in (X months ago from current date)
```

if todays date is 2015-12 and I want 3 months ago, I want the query to be:

```
Select *
From dbo.name
Where date in ('2015-11','2015-10','2015-09')
```

Thanks

Comment: NO you don't want to do it like that at all. You want to use DATEADD. Where date > DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())

Comment: @SeanLange it will work only if date column is of type date or datetime, and by looking at the data, it does not seem like that

Comment: @SeanLange this will ignore any dates in that before today's date.

Comment: You do this with simple string-parsing functions and math.  Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: If your actual data is not the date datatype then you have two problems. You should store dates as dates, not varchar. Secondly you are going to have to force this string that isn't a date to a date so you can do some basic date math.

Comment: exactly, something like Cast( date+'-01' as date)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select *
From dbo.name
Where CAST([Date] + '-01' AS DATE) >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) -3, 0)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if the user's data is only a partial date string, as his sample data indicates.

Comment: @TabAlleman thank you for pointing that out, I have updated my answer to handle it :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your date strings are in `yyyy-mm` format you can do string comparison using < > =.  You just need to convert the current date to varchar(7) using style 126 (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm)

For Example

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @XMonthsAgo INT = 3

DECLARE @Dates TABLE  ([date] varchar(7))

INSERT INTO @Dates VALUES
('2015-09'),('2015-08'),('2015-07'),('2015-06'),('2015-05'),('2015-04'),('2015-03'),
('2015-02'),('2015-01'),('2014-12'),('2014-11'),('2014-10'),('2014-09'),('2014-08'),
('2014-07'),('2014-06'),('2014-05'),('2014-04'),('2014-03'),('2014-02'),('2014-01')

SELECT * 
FROM   @Dates d
WHERE  [date] >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), DATEADD(month, -@XMonthsAgo, @CurrentDate), 126) 
      AND [date] < CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), @CurrentDate, 126)
```

Result

```
date
----
2015-07
2015-06
2015-05
```